# Randomly Map Bits in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I am trying to create a simple, synthesizable module that randomly maps bits of an output to bits of the input without duplicates.  For example, something like this for 8-bit in/out:

```
module Scrambler(in, out);
    parameter WIDTH = 8;

    input wire [WIDTH-1:0] in;
    output wire [WIDTH-1:0] out;

    assign out[0] = in[6];
    assign out[1] = in[5];
    assign out[2] = in[3];
    assign out[3] = in[7];
    assign out[4] = in[1];
    assign out[5] = in[4];
    assign out[6] = in[0];
    assign out[7] = in[2];
endmodule
```

I want to replace the series of assign statements with a generate block so the width of the input/output can be fully parameterized.   I just cannot think of a way to create a cyclic series of random values only at synthesis time.  The mapping will never need to change after synthesis.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong tool for the job, like trying to drive a nail with the butt of a screwdriver.  Use a hammer, like these few lines of Perl (or a hammer of your own choosing):

```perl
use List::Util qw(shuffle);
my $n = shift() - 1;
my @arr = shuffle(0 .. $n);
print "assign out[$_] = in[$arr[$_]];\n" for 0 .. $n;
```

We all use auto-generated Verilog code.  This is no different.  Just copy'n'paste the output into your Verilog file.